# CommCareHQ Exports to display in the Order they Appear in Form Builder

Tags: commcare

When doing a form or case export from CommCareHQ, what would be the most straight forward way to have the data export display with the Question IDs in the order in which they display in the form builder (as opposed to alphabetical order)?
Would Excel Dashboards be the best solution?

Answer (score 2):

Question IDs in form exports should appear in the order of the questions in the form at the time that you create the export. If your form structure has changed and you want your export to match, you would have to manually go in and change the order by dragging the questions.

For case exports you would need to manually go in and reorder them while setting up the export.

Unfortunately I am not aware of a non-manual way to configure the order.

Comment: Also one other note on that. If you change the order of your form, you can create a new export and it should always reflect the current order of your form.